# What should I do with unplanted narcissus/daffodil onions outside of planting season?

Tags: flowers, bulbs, seed-saving, planting-times, daffodils

I have 4-5 "new" narcissus onions on hand, but the planting season is over now (beginning of March). They should be sprouting now.

Here is the [exact variety](https://www.gardenia.net/plant/narcissus-salome-large-cupped-daffodil).

What should I do with them?

- Will I confuse their cycles if I plant them now, so should I somehow safekeep them?
- Should I just plant them now and they'll do whatever they do and be fine until next sprouting season?
- If I should avoid planting them now, what is the best way to safekeep a narcissus for at least 6 months?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plant them now, although I doubt you'll get any flowers this year. Don't remove the leaves before they completely fade. You can keep the bulbs in the ground without taking them out every year until they are too crowded - it will take a few years until they divide that much to become crowded.

If you don't plant the bulbs, they might shrivel too much and die until autumn. In fact, I have kept the bulbs from yellow daffodils (Narcissus pseudonarcissus) that I dug out last spring and forgot to plant last autumn. I found them ten days ago and planted them, although they were very shrivelled. Of course I could put them in the refrigerator for a few weeks, but I have a small fridge. If you want to, you can try.

Comment: You'd be surprised - I've seen larger healthy bulbs throw up flowers even un-planted. You're right that in general the best way to store bulbs is not to store them but plant them!

Comment: @Georgeofalltrades You gave me hope, thanks!